# Covariates in regression difference in difference

Tags: regression, difference-in-difference, case-control-study

I am posting today because I got some issues to understand how to add covariates in a regression difference in difference.

I understand the primary goal of the regression difference in difference. I now want to add covariates (new features in my words) to my model in order to increase the statistical power of my model (which had a 0 R²) before adding new covariates.

The thing I cant figure out is the type of covariates, here in my data, i have two rows for each individual (pre / post treatment) and only the 3 main features of the model, which are period_dummy, treatment_dummy, treatment_dummy*period_dummy are changing per individual.

Is there a restriction on the type of covariate to add ? Should they be related in one case for one individual, to the pre period, and in the other case for the same individual to the post period ? Or can I add more general features that are not related to the pre / post periods and then for one individual, the two rows related to the pre / post period will have the exact same features ?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

You must first ask what covariates would you have selected had this been a cross-sectional study. For that, you should browse related questions on this site, or other materials. In inferential statistics, the $R^2$ is not a measure of model power, so you may be asking the right question for the wrong reasons.

However, an $R^2$ of 0 is virtually impossible, unless very strange and unlikely assumptions have to be met like the outcome being centered (you model mean difference in a prospective study and there is no growth?) and time, intervention, and their interaction being mathematically orthogonal to the outcome as well.

It is good to at least consider covariate adjustment in difference-in-difference models because baseline measures often have measurement error, limiting the ability of those measures to serve as historical controls. Adjustment for covariates which predict the outcome but are not caused by the intervention improve power.

Comment: AdamO, thanks for your answer first of all.

Could you develop on this "You must first ask what covariates would you have selected had this been a cross-sectional study", I am not use to this kind of subjects, but I would like to understand more how to answer the question I am facing.

Comment: @AAissat unfortunately, I cannot (in the scope of a comment) do so. I think the best approach is to familiarize yourself with the applied literature as well as some coursework, books, or other. A good discussion about variable selection in multivariate modeling can be found in "Regression Methods in Biostatistics" by Vittinghoff et al. The discussion of confounding, precision variables, and mediation is particularly relevant.